# replace "\\' to '\' in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using PayWay payment gateway.
I want to put the pay certificate File path in the web.config file.
so I add like this

```
 <add key="PayWayPath" value="c:\payway\ccapi.q0&amp;logDirectory=c:\payway"/>
```

the I call in my web form like this.

```
  String initParams = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayWayPath"];
```

My initParams like this

```
initParams  = c:\\payway\\ccapi.q0&amp;logDirectory=c:\\payway
```

but I need to get like this output.

```
initParams  = c:\payway\ccapi.q0&amp;logDirectory=c:\payway
```

I try this things. But non of the work

```
      initParams = initParams.Replace("\\\\", "\\");  
 initParams = Regex.Replace(initParams, @"[\\ ]", "\");
```

So how can I do it?

Comment: Backslashes get escaped automatically in the IDE. Replacing it won't work. But if you are using the string, I think you shouldn't see the escape sequence.

Comment: you can use
`input = input.Replace(@"\\", @"\");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need anything.**

First one is only seems on IDE, when you write it, it will be without slashes..

Let's try it;

```
string s = "c:\\payway\\ccapi.q0&amp;logDirectory=c:\\payway";
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output will be;

```
c:\payway\ccapi.q0&amp;logDirectory=c:\payway
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/2PJyJB).

Irrelevant but if you want to write your strings exactly what they are, you can use `@` is called *[verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)*

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you won't need to do anything more. If the string already has the slashes escaped, when you "print" that value, it will appear as you want it to (ie. single slashes only)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

```
initParams = initParams.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
```